# Android app - bundle videos in apk is a bad idea?

Tags: android, video, mp4, apk

I have an Android app (client app) which requires several videos to be available in the app for local playback. Average video is 10MB+. I don't believe the videos will be updated often, if at all..
This app might not ever be hosted on Google Play, but perhaps it will in the future. It is currently viewed as a corporate app.

With all mp4 videos included in the app (in the raw folder), the apk is 300-500MB (depending on the quality/compression used). This has sometimes failed to install on certain tablets because it times out, or after 20 minutes, it finds out that there isn't enough storage space left on the device...

**Is it a bad idea to include 300+MB of videos in the apk to begin with?** Since it is a corporate app, perhaps there is no issue with user adoption - all customers want the app. 
However, do .apks get deflated into a separate folder, and thus using up double the memory on the phone? I assume .apks get installed into a different partition than sdcard or other "external storage" locations..

My thought is to create a simple apk without videos, and then have an AsyncTask or Service (or queue mechanism such as Jake Wharton's [Tape](http://square.github.com/tape/) project, or even [AndroidQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)) to handle an auto-download of the videos when the app is first launched. But then the client has to host all of these video files along with an .apk file. I personally don't see this as an issue.

Also, if the videos are separated from the .apk, then it opens up the possibility of Kindle and Nook devices as well, as these markets have MB limits to the .apk file size...

*Should this Android app be all-videos-in-one, or split up the .apk and videos files?*

Comment: even play allows you to add 2 expansseion files upto 2 gb which is downloaded with the apk to a shared location so you can better go for the second approach of asyncronusly downloading that is what is done by play too and check weather the files are available on start up to download it chec apk expannsion in android developers site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think allowing 300 MB of video in the app itself is a good idea even though it’s a corporate private app.

Have you seen the apps in PlayStore and how they handle larger files? Especially games. First they’ll allow you to download the core of the app. Once core is downloaded it’ll download the files that are mandatory to work (probably the initial video that will play when user logs in). Afterwards you can let user to download videos from server on necessary basis than forcing them to download all the videos.

Another option would be to let them stream the video. So you don’t have to download any video to the device. Think of devices that has very limited storage, this would be the ideal solution for them.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle big video into apk is definitely a bad idea. It even leads to trouble of installing apk on device.